# centos 8: debuginfo-install can't find kernel-debuginfo package

Tags: linux, centos, yum, debug

I have a machine with `CentOS-8` installed, kernel shipped with it is 4.18.0. I need to install debiginfo package:

```
% sudo dnf debuginfo-install kernel-4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64
enabling epel-modular-debuginfo repository
enabling epel-debuginfo repository
Last metadata expiration check: 0:22:04 ago on Thu 03 Dec 2020 04:51:14 PM EST.
Could not find debuginfo package for the following installed packages: kernel-4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64
Could not find debugsource package for the following installed packages: kernel-4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
%
```

Although `yum search` finds it:

```
% yum search kernel-debug
...
kernel-debug.x86_64 : kernel meta-package for the debug kernel
...
%
```

I thought `debuginfo-install` is the right way to install packages with debuginfo. What should I do to get it to work for me?

Thanks.

Comment: debuginfo packages only apply to userland, not the kernel itself. What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I need kernel with debug information in order to do performance analysis with `perf`

Comment: So install the debug kernel. It looks like you already found it.

Comment: Documentation about `perf` usage suggested to install kernel with debug symbols via `debuginfo-install`, so I followed it.

Comment: What documentation?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, https://netdevconf.info/0.1/docs/sowa-perf-analytics.pdf  slide 2

Comment: That's someone's slides from a conference talk, not really documentation, and it looks like you found an error in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.  On CentOS 8,

1. You can modify `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` to set `enable=1` and then run `yum install kernel-debuginfo` or
2. You can do `yum --enablerepo="base-debuginfo" install kernel-debuginfo`

Either of these worked on my system.  Be sure you have plenty of space on your disk.  The installed size is 3.1GB.

**NOTE** :

1. You'll want to inspect the kernel version used in `kernel-debuginfo` (i.e. `yum info kernel-debuginfo`) to ensure that it is the same version as your kernel (i.e. `uname -r`).
2. If they differ, you may need to go hunting for the correct versions of `kernel-debuginfo` and `kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64`. I used the `baseurl` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` as a template to find where to look. For CentOS 8.1 look [here](http://debuginfo.centos.org/8/x86_64/Packages/).

Comment: On Rocky Linux 8 the file is called Rocky-Debuginfo.repo